# ListView in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

Is that possible to put a `ListView` in a `LinearLayout` or any other layout without using XML code?

This is my original code:

```
public class PickEF extends Activity {


    /*TextView bookingPeriod = new TextView(this);
    bookingPeriod.setText("Your booking period are: "+this.getIntent().getStringExtra("checked"));
    TextView available = new TextView(this);
    available.setText("These are the available items during your booking period: ");

    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);

    RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
    RadioButton r1 = new RadioButton(this);
    r1.setText("Radio Button1");
    RadioButton r2 = new RadioButton(this);
    r2.setText("Radio Button2");
    r1

    rg.addView(r1);
    rg.addView(r2);
    tl.addView(rg);


    setContentView(tl);*/

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] room = new String[] {
            "N001",
            "N003",
            "N004",
            "N007"

    };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
            R.drawable.tutorialroom,
            R.drawable.tutorialroom,
            R.drawable.tutorialroom,
            R.drawable.tutorialroom

    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] capacity = new String[]{
        "40",
        "40",
        "40",
        "40",

    };

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] lecture = new String[] {
            "LDK1",
            "LDK2",
            "LDK4",
            "LDK5"

    };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] icon = new int[]{
            R.drawable.lecturehall,
            R.drawable.lecturehall,
            R.drawable.lecturehall,
            R.drawable.lecturehall

    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] capacity2 = new String[]{
        "140",
        "140",
        "140",
        "140",

    };


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_ef);        

        TextView bookingPeriod = new TextView(this);
        bookingPeriod.setText("Your booking period: "+this.getIntent().getStringExtra("checked"));
        TextView type = new TextView(this);
        type.setText(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));


        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
        if(type.equals("lhall"))
        {


            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                hm.put("txt", "Room Number : " + lecture[i]);
                hm.put("cur","Capacity : " + capacity2[i]);
                hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(icon[i]) );            
                aList.add(hm);        
            }
        }
        else{


            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                hm.put("txt", "Room Number : " + room[i]);
                hm.put("cur","Capacity : " + capacity[i]);
                hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );            
                aList.add(hm);        
            }

        }
        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};        

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);      


        // Item Click Listener for the listview
        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {
                // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
                LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;

                // Getting the inner Linear Layout
                LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout ) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

                // Getting the Country TextView
                TextView tvCountry = (TextView) linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tvCountry.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        // Setting the item click listener for the listview
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.addView(listView, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        setContentView(ll);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pick_e, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is the logcat:

> 08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961): Process: my.edu.utar.sofebos, PID: 2961
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.edu.utar.sofebos/my.edu.utar.sofebos.PickEF}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3562)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at my.edu.utar.sofebos.PickEF.onCreate(PickEF.java:180)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   08-22 19:08:06.529: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     ... 11 more

Comment: Your title and body are asking two different things. "Under" or "in"? Anyway, it's certainly possible but easier in xml if you don't **need* to do it in Java. Post the stacktrace from the crash.

Comment: Hmm, I would like to do as what I code in the body. Is it consider under?

Comment: You are adding it to your `LinearLayout` which is fine. But we still can't help you without the logcat so we can know what the error is.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

@codeMagic Is this the one you looking for?

Comment: Yes but post the complete stacktrace in your original post. Also post your complete onCreate (), assuming that's where this code is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `ll.addView()` add this:

```
((ViewGroup)listview.getParent()).removeView(listview);
```

Comment: Ya, I only used it once.

Comment: You mean

setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_ef); 
and
setContentView(ll); ?

Comment: Yes, try to remove `setContentView(ll);` and see if there is still exception.

Comment: If I try to remove `setContentView(ll)` then I will not able to put the ListView in LinearLayout right?

Comment: Try to remove to check if this is the problem, you need to find the problem first, and then solve it.

Comment: I tried to `remove'setContentView(ll)`, but the problem still exist.
However, i try to remove 
`LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
ll.addView(listView);
setContentView(ll);`
Then the application able to run.

Comment: Remove line every time, and find the problematic line.

Comment: This is the problem line `ll.addView(listView)`

Comment: Changed my answer, check it.

Comment: It solved my problem! Thanks much!!
But may I know the problem?

Comment: Same as the exception says, the list view already had a parent, this line remove the `listview` connection to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the listview some kind of layout restriction or definition.

change

```
ll.addView(lv);
```

to

```
ll.addView(lv, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

I think it will work properly.Let me know if your issue solved.